# shell_exec wont work from crontab

Tags: php, cron, shell-exec

I have looked at other answers they dont fit to this case.
I am using the full path to the file. Code I copied is simplified.

run.php contains:

```
shell_exec("php /var/www/html/sync/chourly.php $position $quotientx > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

if I use manually `php run.php` - it works great.
here is the line on crontab -e :

```
05 * * * *  /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://sync.eeeww.com/run.php
```

again the file run.php starts BUT chourly.php doesn't start. I am using centOS 6
any suggestions please? 
Addition: I checked the permissions I am using ec2-user to run php run.php and crontab is using the same permission. it is able to run the file but shell_exec is where the issue occurs

Comment: so why do you call http// in cron?

Comment: @cpburnz not correct

Comment: it does run. I have 10 other crons setup the same way they all work.

Comment: if sync.bitpine.com is your site you can just use `php run.php` as the cron job

Comment: that's not the problem. the issue is shell_exec not starting chourly.php

Comment: Check the webserver permissions since thats the one executing your script.

Comment: I already did Jelle. I wrote it with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is /var/www/html/sync/chourly.php using `$SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ? Since you're explicitly calling the php interpreter (not mod_php), a `$SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] call will not work as you expect.

Try manually running the cron from shell to see where it's failing.

```
cd /
su - your_httpd_usersame -c "/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://sync.bitpine.com/run.php"
```

Comment: su -u httpd -c "/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://sync.bitpine.com/run.php" returns the options and documentation for su command. It doesn't work

Comment: so what is it that i need to do so it works using cron ?

Comment: Did it spat an error when you manually ran the above command?

Comment: unable to open file is the error sorry for the delay

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you out without additional more details about the error and the code in the script...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68364/discussion-between-alpha01-and-stacknoob).