# running system() from crontab doesnt open the file. php

Tags: php, centos, exec, cron, shell-exec

running system() from crontab returns an error "unable to open file"
the path is correct.
crontab content :

```
## test
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://example.org/testshell.php
```

php inside testshell.php :

```
$last_line = shell_exec('php /var/www/html/shellrun.php', $retval);
```

if i run it from php CLI it works great. but if the crontab calls testshell.php then shellrun.php doesnt start.
I got it to email me the error and it says "unable to open file"
any thoughts / ideas? 
thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell\_exec wont work from crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806488/shell-exec-wont-work-from-crontab)

Comment: @glennjackman hey glenn did you post a suggestion or helped? I don't see it

Comment: I did not. Why are you asking the same question?